# XOR IP address and port Number

Tags: ip-address, xor, fingerprint

I got an expression to fingerprint certain kinds of IP packets.
But I don't know how to decode the expression

The expression is as follows,

```
    ip_id = ip_address XOR port_number XOR sequence_number
```

How to get the value of ip_id??
port_number and sequence_number are integers.So it can be XORed. But how can we XOR IP_address and an integer?

Thanks in advance
Subin

Comment: `ip_address` is an integer too if you want it to be, gets a bit hairy if you want to support IPv6 though, then you suddenly have a 128bit integer to deal with.

Comment: @harold Thank you for you reply. How can I convert IP address to integer?

Comment: Depends on what format you have it in in the first place. Typically it's already an integer.

Comment: ohh..ok..Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the functions inet_aton and inet_ntoa.

These functions are similar to ntoa and aton, parsing a string representation to a native data format and vice versa.

An IP-Adress consists of 4 bytes:

```
aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd
```

That makes 4 bytes in total, thus you can combine them to 1 single integer (which is also 4 bytes = 32 bits).

Comment: Ohh..Ok..Thank you for your reply.